# Extract specific value from JSON column in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

Firstly i had json that i converted into pandas Dataframe

```
ad_data = '{
   "data":[
      {
         "impressions":"11111",
         "spend":"123",
         "conversions":[
            {
               "action_type":"start_trial_total",
               "value":"6"
            },
            {
               "action_type":"subscribe_mobile_app",
               "value":"3"
            }
         ],
         "outbound_clicks_ctr":[
            {
               "action_type":"outbound_click",
               "value":"1.869306"
            }
         ],
         "date_start":"2020-01-23",
         "date_stop":"2020-01-23"
      },
      {
         "impressions":"22222",
         "spend":"321",
            {
               "action_type":"start_trial_total",
               "value":"6"
            }
         ],
         "outbound_clicks_ctr":[
            {
               "action_type":"outbound_click",
               "value":"2.328902"
            }
         ],
         "date_start":"2020-01-24",
         "date_stop":"2020-01-24"
      }
   ]
}'

df = pd.DataFrame(ad_data['data'])
```

So i get Dataframe

| impressions | spend | conversions | outbound_clicks_ctr | date_start | date_stop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 123 | [{'action_type': 'start_trial_total', 'value': '6'}, {'action_type': 'subscribe_mobile_app', 'value': '3'}] | [{'action_type': 'outbound_click', 'value': '1... | 2020-01-23 | 2021-01-23 |
| 22222 | 312 | [{'action_type': 'start_trial_total', 'value': '6'}] | [{'action_type': 'outbound_click', 'value': '1... | 2020-01-24 | 2020-01-24 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

And now i want to extract values from column **conversions** only where *subscribe_mobile_app* exists, in other case insert 0 and get table like this

| impressions | spend | conversions | outbound_clicks_ctr | date_start | date_stop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 123 | **3** | [{'action_type': 'outbound_click', 'value': '1... | 2020-01-23 | 2021-01-23 |
| 22222 | 312 | **0** | [{'action_type': 'outbound_click', 'value': '1... | 2020-01-24 | 2020-01-24 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

How can i get result like this with pandas?

i also tried to extract values before converting JSON into Dataframe with loop and add it to the list, and then add to Dataframe as new column but this plan didn't work for me too

```
subscribe = []
for i in ad_data['data']:
    for sub in i['conversions']:
        if sub['action_type'] == 'subscribe_mobile_app':
            subscribe.append(sub['value'])
        else:
            subscribe.append(None)
```

result was something like this:

```
[None,3,None, None...]
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY:

```
import ast

result = []
for i in df.conversions.values:
    f = False
    for k in ast.literal_eval(i):
        if 'subscribe_mobile_app' in k.values():
            result.append(k['value'])
            f = True
            break
    if not f:
        result.append(0)

df.conversions = result
```

Comment: It return error:
ValueError: malformed node or string: [{'action_type': 'start_trial_total', 'value': '6'}, {'action_type': 'subscribe_mobile_app', 'value': '3'},

Comment: Try once without ast.literal_eval

Comment: without ast.literal_eval works excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since `conversions` column of your dataframe contains list of dictionaries over which you want to operate.
You can create a separate function that can accept these lists as parameter, and then check within the dictionaries in those lists, if you have *`subscribe_mobile_app`* in them, and then return the value accordingly:

```
def subscribe_mobile_app_values(lst):
     val = 0
     for i in lst:
         if i["action_type"] == "subscribe_mobile_app":
             val = i["value"]
             break
     return val
```

Then just apply this function to the conversions column in your dataframe:

```
df['conversions'] = df['conversions'].apply(subscribe_mobile_app_values)
```

Comment: So as I understand it, you want a function which can return the value of the action_type you mention to it?

Comment: @mrDaft  You wanted to improve the `subscribe_mobile_app_values` function as per your previous comment which seems to have got deleted now. Just checking if you need any more help in this answer, or has it solved your problem?